# openerp aeroo reports show customer address in ods file

Tags: report, odoo

I want to display the customer address in the .ods file just the way it appears on the invoice. How can I achieve this? There is no address field in res_ partner. I tried looking for the method OpenERP uses to display the address but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In invoicing their is no field like address, but address comes through the **context="{'search_default_customer':1, 'show_address': 1}** which is apply on Customer field.

If you want to display address on the report than you need to do this

**display_address(object.partner_id)**

Hope this will help you.